# I would like to try kde (kubuntu) without losing any data and a possibility to revert back

Tags: unity, system-installation, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I have an old PC having 2 GB of RAM and an old dual core Intel processor (2.5 GHz) and I believe it has an integrated intel graphics chip of 256 MB.
So recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and loved it and have been using it a lot.
But lately it sometimes stops responding and crashes and I have to use the console (ctrl alt f4) to reboot. 
I read KDE is less demanding than Unity so I am thinking of giving it a shot but in case if I don't like it, I want to have an option of reverting back too.

PS: The PC is on dual boot with perhaps Windows Vista (or 7 maybe) which I don't use. It's on a separate partition and GRUB asks me to choose the OS.
EDIT: And one more thing, I earlier used 15.10 Ubuntu 64 bit(my computer does support 64 bit)and it seemed to lag significantly especially when doing graphical stuff like changing backgrounds or themes. Later on I upgraded to LTS 16.04 but chose 32 bit and it is slightly better. 
So was the change due to coming to 32 bit or using the LTS?

Comment: Try it from a USB? You can install KDE on your current install too `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` however, removal is difficult.

Comment: I would go with Mark's suggestion. virtualbox is going to be problematic (it prefers more RAM ).   You could also make a triple boot or overwrite Windows and install it in there). For a test though I would use an USB install. kUbuntu though is less demanding but not that much. xUbuntu and lUbuntu would be a better option.

Comment: You don't know which windows installed ?Please check more accurate information translate to more accurate suggestions.

Comment: I checked. It's windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

KDE is using about 700MB of RAM. If you want something faster try [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

If you just want the Desktop environment, then install it with `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`. If you won´t like it, you can remove it with `tasksel`

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

find Kubuntu desktop in the list and remove its selection. Read and confirm the prompts.
After this run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: 1. There is NO need to install tasksel ("purge" the desktop would be enough). 2. This will install a desktop within his current system violating the 2nd part of his question (the ability to revert without problems; it -can- lead to problems).

Comment: So if I "purge" the  package, wouldn't it automatically revert to unity?

Comment: No, I am afraid not. The desktop environments might work side by side, but it is difficult or impossible  to remove one of them without damage to the other desktop environment.

Comment: This is kind of frustrating. I mean it sounds simple enough in principle! Assuming I triple boot how can I safely remove one of them after I have decided?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ubuntu flavours *live* without installing, booted from a USB drive or DVD disk. In a USB drive you can also create a *persistent live* system or even an installed system (installed like into an internal drive), but it is often enough with a live or persistent live system for testing.

*This way you can easily try several flavours of Ubuntu* without touching the internal drive. And after testing you decide to keep standard Ubuntu or switch to one of the flavours with another desktop environment.

See the following link for more details,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

*Edit:* My guess is that Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu will be your choice after testing.

Comment: I looked at mate and lubuntu too. But preferred the interface of kde.

Comment: So if I try kubuntu from live USB would it be possible for it to install it over Ubuntu?

Comment: It is always possible to overwrite a previous operating system. But maybe you mean 'add `kubuntu-desktop` to the existing standard Ubuntu? It might work well, but might cause problems, and it is very difficult to undo unless you can restore the system for a complete backup.

Comment: So is it possible to create a restoring image? Something along the lines of nandroid backups would be really helpful if possible.

Comment: You can use Clonezilla and make a compressed image. The image is a directory with a number of files. http://clonezilla.org/ - You can and should check that you can restore from the image to another (empty) drive of at least the same size as the original drive. Otherwise you cannot rely on your backup. - A simpler alternative is to backup only your personal files and be prepared to make a fresh installation of Kubuntu, which is not too difficult. Add application programs when you need them.

Comment: Yeah, seems that is the only way.